# Não consigo obter XPATH da caixa comentário no YouTube

Tags: python, youtube, xpath

Preciso conseguir comentar no YouTube, porém o XPATH não dá certo, mesmo com os parâmetros certos, já tentei com ID e ELEMENT porém não obtive sucesso.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import keyboard
import time

#--------------pra comentar faça login no gmail inserindo os paramentros login_Gmail,password_Gmail.--------------#

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\FAMILIA\Downloads\aaa\chromedriver.exe")
x = driver.get('https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F&service=mail&sacu=1&rip=1&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin')
time.sleep(2)

login_Gmail = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="identifierId"]').send_keys('SEU EMAIL GMAIL')
print('e-mail ok')
time.sleep(2)
keyboard.press('Enter')
time.sleep(2)
password_Gmail = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="password"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/input').send_keys('SUA SENHA GMAIL')
print('senha ok')
time.sleep(2)
keyboard.press('Enter')
print('login feito')
time.sleep(1)
x = driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9nV9GNjXFDo&list=RD9nV9GNjXFDo&start_radio=1')
time.sleep(3)
print('youtube video')
comment_New = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="contenteditable-textarea"]').send_keys('TEXTO A SER COEMNTADO')  ###ESTA PARTE QUE ESTOUC COM PROBLEMAS###
keyboard.press('Enter')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu fiz alguns teste e consegui comentar da seguinte forma:

Primeiro, para o campo de comentários aparecer, é necessário descer a página um pouco. Então usei:

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 350)")
```

onde 350 é o valor Y para scrollar para baixo (no meu caso, de 0 a 1080, pela resolução do monitor)

Depois, para o comentário ficar habilitado, você precisa clicar no elemento antes. Para isso, utilizei:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="placeholder-area"]').click()
```

O código final ficou assim:

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 350)")
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="placeholder-area"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="contenteditable-root"]').send_keys('Teste')
```